# gorm: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to add some foreign keys to my models in gorm. I've done exactly the same as the documentation for adding foreign keys.
these are the models

**Album model:**

```
type Album struct {
    gorm.Model
    Artists     []Artist
    Name        string
    ReleaseDate time.Time
    Genre       Genre
    Picture     string
}
```

**Artist model:**

```
type Artist struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string
    Description string
    YearsActive string
}
```

**Genre model:**

```
type Genre struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string
    Description string
}
```

**Track model:**

```
type Track struct {
    gorm.Model
    Album    Album
    Name     string
    Artists  []Artist
    Playtime time.Duration
}
```

and the code I'm using for creating tables:

```
DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(&models.Genre{}, &models.Artist{}, &models.Album{}, &models.Track{})
```

what am I doing wrong here? I'm new to the foreign key concept. I just want to associate tracks with their artists and albums respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the issue is that gorm does not know how to connect album with artist (same for others), you need to add `AlbumID` field to `Artist` struct in order for gorm to know what is the connection between structs..

Here is the example for all structs that you presented:

**Album model:**

```
type Album struct {
    gorm.Model
    Artists     []Artist `gorm:"many2many:album_artists;"`
    Name        string
    ReleaseDate time.Time
    GenreID     uint
    Genre       Genre
    Picture     string
}
```

Since album and artist is many-to-many relationship, you may back-reference it depending on your needs [check here](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html)

**Artist model:**

```
type Artist struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string
    Description string
    YearsActive string
}
```

**Genre model:**

```
type Genre struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string
    Description string
}
```

**Track model:**

```
type Track struct {
    gorm.Model
    AlbumID  uint
    Album    Album
    Name     string
    Artists  []Artist  `gorm:"many2many:track_artists;"`  // you may back reference this too
    Playtime time.Duration
}
```

And now you can use this:

```
DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(&models.Genre{}, &models.Artist{}, &models.Album{}, &models.Track{})
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked as expected. I have another question. is there a reason that we should create new tables to save relations between the models? I have much to learn about databases so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: well since album can have many tracks, and tracks can have many artists, you dont need artists inside album, you can access them trough tracks.

Comment: thanks. that's a good suggestion.